# cycle through matches by index with re.finditer

Tags: python, regex

I want to know how to navigate by index the object produced by a finditer regex operation.

My string is `s = "fish oil X22 stack peanut C4"`

Here is my code:

```
import re
words = re.finditer('\S+', s)
has_digits = re.compile(r'\d').search
for word in words:
    if has_digits(word.group()):
        print (the word that is two words back)
```

Desired output =

```
fish
stack
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `deque` to hold the elements.  Then this becomes easy:

```
import re
from collections import deque
s = 'fish oil X22 stack peanut C4'
words = re.finditer('\S+', s)
has_digits = re.compile(r'\d').search
deq = deque([],2)
for word in words:
    wordtxt = word.group()
    if has_digits(wordtxt):
        print (deq[0])
    deq.append(wordtxt)
```

It's a little unclear what should happen with the string:

```
s = 'fish oil X22 stack C4'
```

Should it print "fish" and "oil" or "fish" and "X22".  Also, what if the first substring is "X22"?  In my answer, this will cause an `IndexError`, but it's hard to know what you want to do with that...

Comment: How do I check if the first substring is X22 to avoid the error?

Comment: You could just wrap it in a try/except.  What do you want to happen?  what if the second element is X22?  there are a number of options, but the best choice really depends on the behavior you want in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
import re
import itertools as it

s = "fish oil X22 stack peanut C4"
words = re.finditer('\S+', s)
has_digits = re.compile(r'\d').search
words, words_copy = it.tee(words)
next(words); next(words)       #Skip the first two words of one iterator
for word, back_word in it.izip(words, words_copy):
    if has_digits(word.group()):
            print(back_word.group())
```